# Fresco play gif from file

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using this code to show just a simple image from file. But how can i play gif?

```
var CatalogMain = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString(), "NewFolder");

SimpleDraweeView MainImage = FindViewById<SimpleDraweeView>(Resource.Id.MainImageView);
Android.Net.Uri imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(CatalogMain, "Main.gif"));// For files on device
MainImage.SetImageURI(imageUri);
```

I also found this code, but i'm taking several errors. I dont know how i need to convert it for playing with xamarin.

```
Uri uri;
DraweeController controller = Fresco.NewDraweeControllerBuilder()
                                    .SetUri(imageUri)
                                    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                                    .build();
mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

I'm getting following errors

> Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DraweeController' could not be found.
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'mSimpleDraweeView' does not exist in the current.
>
> Error  CS1061  'ISimpleDraweeControllerBuilder' does not contain a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.Parse("http://img.huofar.com/data/jiankangrenwu/shizi.gif");

PipelineDraweeControllerBuilder pdcb= (PipelineDraweeControllerBuilder) Fresco.NewDraweeControllerBuilder()
                                               .SetAutoPlayAnimations(true);
IDraweeController draweeController = pdcb.SetUri(Uri.Parse("res://" + PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.test)).Build();

SimpleDraweeView img = FindViewById<SimpleDraweeView>(Resource.Id.img);
img.Controller = draweeController;
```

But, this can only load the picture, the gif can't be played. Because `Fresco` need `com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0` to support gif (look [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html)).

And [NAXAM/fresco-android-binding](https://github.com/NAXAM/fresco-android-binding) did't bind `com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0` in their nuget. After execute `Install-Package Naxam.Fresco.Droid` on Package Manager Console, you will add five packages into your project, they are:

- `Naxam.Fresco.Droid`
- `Naxam.FrescoCore.Droid`
- `Naxam.FrescoDrawee.Droid`
- `Naxam.FrescoImagePipeline.Droid`
- `Naxam.FrescoImagePipelineBase.Droid`.

But there is no `animated-gif`.

So, I suggest you to use [glide](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/) to load gif, [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96768/load-loading-gif-in-glide) is a simple:

```
var CatalogMain = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString(), "dbsoft");
Glide.With(this).AsGif().Load(new File(CatalogMain, "Main.gif")).Into(MainImage);
```

I have made a [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/GifTest) which loads the gif with both Fresco and Gilde.